# How to send an array with jquery to php script?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am sending an array to php script using an Ajax call, but I am not able to access that array in php.

Here is my code:

```
seats = ["s4","s6","s9","s24"];
sendBookedSeats(seats);

function sendBookedSeats(seats){
    console.log(seats);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php",
      data: {
        'seats' : seats,
      }
    })
}
```

How do I access the array `seats` in my php script?

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($_POST);` in `index.php`?

Comment: add contentType property

Comment: You need to add more context, when are sending the data, are you using a form? And in what file is this code located, is that also `index.php`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to search through a JSON Array in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987611/how-to-search-through-a-json-array-in-php)

Comment: also see http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: What do you see when you do a print_R($_POST) in php page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send data as json:

```
seats= ["s4","s6","s9","s24"];
sendBookedSeats(seats);



function sendBookedSeats(seats){
    console.log(seats);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php",
      data: {
        'seats' : JSON.stringify(seats),
      }
    })
}
```

PHP:

```
json_decode($_POST["seats"]);
```

Comment: Hi Hannes, non of the answer is accepted. Did you get the solution yet or not. Did you try my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendBookedSeats(seats){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: "index.php",
      data: {
        'seats' : seats,
      }
    })
}
```

Add content Type to your ajax call.