# How to search through Json by keyword in PHP?

Tags: php, json

i am currently having problem with searching through json file, and i am searching and showing faculties based on searched word but it only shows the value when i type in the full name, how can i get search to work if i like only type first few characters and show the results with name starting with it.

here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['search_word']))
{
$search_word=$_GET['search_word'];
$string = file_get_contents("faculty_info.json");
$jfo = json_decode($string);
// copy the posts array to a php var
$posts = $jfo->faculty_info;
// listing posts
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    if($post->name == "$search_word"){
    echo $post->name;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $post->division;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $post->school;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $post->designation;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $post->email;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $post->room;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: you don't have json. you've decoded it, and now have a plain old php data structure. you rummage around inside that structure like you would any OTHER php data structure.

Comment: can you mention what's wrong and how can i improve about what you are saying?

Comment: you'd have to explain exactly what this `$search_word` is, and what's in those fields. because right now, you're doing an exact string match, so searching for the letter `r` is not doing to match `Doctor`, because `r != Doctor`.

Comment: refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987611/how-to-search-through-a-json-array-in-php

Comment: So, I've noticed a lot of these JSON related questions recently. Who's your teacher and why do you think we'll do your homework for you?

Comment: $search_word is the word that is being searched in the html form so it is exact string match with the PHP in order to run properly.

Comment: @jjwdesign with all respect it's not like that and it's not some kind of homework. i did search a lot but all stack posts led me to searching with exact string match!

Comment: You can use jsond decode($string,1) to have `$posts` as array and use `preg_grep` to search a regex pattern in array or `array_search()`to find exact match

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$post->name = 'How are you?';
$search_word = "How";

$pos = strpos($post->name, $search_word);

if ( $pos !== false && $pos == 0) {
   echo 'found';
   //do your script
}
```

You may also want to replace `strpos` with `stripos` in case you need to handle case insensitive searches.

Comment: See my updated answer. Not sure if you are looking for this scenario.