# Filter JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json

I assure you that I have read every post about similar problems in here within the last hours. I need to filter these json results for a specific home team id:

```
data: [
    {
        id: 122307,
        weather: null,
        temperature: null,
        commentary: false,
        ht_score: "2-0",
        ft_score: "3-0",
        et_score: null,
        home_team_id: 1370,
        away_team_id: 1279,
        home_score: 3,
        away_score: 0,
        home_score_penalties: 0,
        away_score_penalties: 0,
        formation: {
        home: null,
        away: null
    },...
```

This is my code:

```
$sy_json_match_cal=file_get_contents('url');
$sy_match_cal = json_decode($sy_json_match_cal,true);
$sy_match_calendar = $sy_match_cal['data']; 

$sy_hteam_filter = array_filter($sy_match_calendar, function($obj)
{
    return $obj->home_team_id == 1370;
});
```

Another try(2):

```
foreach($sy_match_cal->data as $item)
{
    if($item->id == 122307)
    {
        echo $item->home_team_id;
    }
}
```

Next to these codes, I have tried several other things which have not worked either. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987611/how-to-search-through-a-json-array-in-php

Comment: Not really unfortunately. Just added my second try above.

Comment: And what do you see with `print_r($item)`?

Comment: Nothing unfortunately :(

Comment: Here is the JSON in case this helps: https://codeshare.io/Ocot7

Comment: And if you print `$sy_match_cal` what do you see?

Comment: `print_r($sy_match_cal);` shows https://codeshare.io/6b5ya

Comment: So this means you have array of arrays. THen why do you use object notation with `->`?

Comment: I do not know how to do that :(