# How to search through nested JSON arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm sorry if I don't use the correct terminology, I'm still learning. I'm trying to figure out how to search a JSON array that has nested arrays in it for a specific value, and then return an associated value.

My problem is similar to this answered question on StackOverflow ([How to search through a JSON Array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987611/how-to-search-through-a-json-array-in-php)), but I want to be able to find an **item by id** in either **people** or **dog** or **any other nested array**. Essentially I want to convert `people` below in the foreach to a wildcard.

Here is my JSON data - http://foothillertech.com/student/webdesign/2018/2018benrud2/tinker/dataIntro2/test/data.json

```
foreach($json->people as $item)
{
    if($item->id == "8097")
    {
        echo $item->content;
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, simply do two loops.

```
$json = json_decode('{
    "people": [
        {
            "id": "8080",
            "content": "foo"
        },
        {
            "id": "8097",
            "content": "bar"
        }
    ],
    "dogs": [
        {
            "id": "8081",
            "content": "spot"
        },
        {
            "id": "8091",
            "content": "max"
        }
    ]
}');

foreach($json as $key=>$value){
    //$key = people or dogs
    //$value = stdClass()

    foreach($value as $item)
    {
        if($item->id == "8097")
        {
            echo $item->content;
        }
    }    
}
```

Output

```
bar
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/727dd67d981e1637e1525a6bb994328cb6408b82)

If we used `8081` instead of `8097` I would expect to get 'spot`.  And testing that, I do indeed get that (which is in dogs).

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Not only did you help me with my problem, but you also taught me the proper use `as $key=>$value` in a foreach. I've always thought that you have to ask for a specific item. If I'm correct, this method will allow me to pull any "key/value" pair from an array if I know its name. Thanks again!

Comment: If `id` properties are unique, then we should see a `break` used.

Answer (score 2):

If id is unique in the data, you can merge the inner arrays and index them by id.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$merged = array_merge(...array_values($data));
$indexed = array_column($merged, null, 'id');
```

Then you can look up any of the items by id.

```
echo $indexed['8097']['content'] ?? 'not found';
```

This only works if id is unique. If not, indexing by id will result in data loss.